# MySql many to many select only fixed row at joined row

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have one database here

1st table is conversation table

```
___________________________
| id | conversation Name  |
__________________________
|  1 | member and officer |
___________________________
|  2 | member and guests  |
___________________________
```

2nd table is user table

```
_________________
| id | name     |
_________________
|  1 |member    |
_________________
|  2 |officer   |
_________________
|  3 |guest     |
_________________
```

3rd table is conversation_user_involved table

```
_________________________________
| id_conversation | id_user     |
_________________________________
|              1  | 1           |
_________________________________
|              1  | 2           |
_________________________________
|              2  | 1           |
_________________________________
|              2  | 3           |
_________________________________
```

The question is how do I select conversation based on user.

Let say the input user parameter is 1 and 2 so that mean user 1 is member and 2 is officer.
How can I select the conversation member and officer?

I have tried "IN" query but it didnt work.

Comment: err thanks for edit, i appreciate if you have an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

untested:

```
select     id_conversation, conversation_Name
from       conversation_user_involved
inner join conversation on (id_conversation = conversation.id)
where      id_user in (1, 2)
group by   id_conversation
having     count(id_conversation) = 2
```